True variance of coefficients change with redundant explanatory variables MLE?
I am doing a course covering General Linear Statistical Models, where we are studying models of the form $g(y) = X\boldsymbol{\beta}$. We were taught that $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}} \xrightarrow[]{d} MVN(\boldsymbol{\beta}, \mathcal{I}^{-1}(\boldsymbol{\beta}))$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ when estimating a vector of parameters $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ with the MLE (where $\mathcal{I}^{-1}(\boldsymbol{\beta})$ is the fisher information matrix inverse).
Now then, due to the properties of the covariance matrix, the variance of $\beta_i$ is given by $[\mathcal{I}^{-1}(\boldsymbol{\beta})]_{ii}$. My intuition tells me that if we add an irrelevant variable, lets say $\beta_{n+1}$, that has a true value of $0$ then the variance of our initial parameter of interest (\boldsymbol{\beta})]_{ii}, should stay the same. But I can't seem to prove that $[\mathcal{I}^{-1}(\boldsymbol{\beta})]_{ii}$ does in fact stay the same after adding the new variable, thereby increasing the row and column count of the matrix by 1.
It seems like there is no reason why the old inverse fisher $n \times n$ matrix should be contained inside the new $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ inverse fisher matrix. This assumes that the log likelihood remains practically unchanged.
Apologies if I have missed something obvious

I think you are using $n$ to denote different concepts. In the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\beta}$, the $n$ refers to sample size; in the $\beta_{n+1}$ and the information matrix, the $n$ refers to the number of mean parameters.

Adding a predictor variable $u$ with true coefficient $\beta_{p+1}=0$ is insufficient for the information matrix to be untouched. The issue is the that $u$ might be correlated with other predictors, i.e., other columns of $X$, even if the true $\beta_{p+1}=0$.
You intuition would be correct if $X'u\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. In this case, the limiting Gram matrix is block diagonal; so is its inverse.

Thanks for the answer
